# Deprecated java classes in stdlib.jar

Tags: java, libraries

I'm facing a problem with deprecated classes in a set of Libs for the [Programming in Java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) tutorial.
Currently, I'm trying to run [ThreeSum.java](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/ThreeSum.java.html) and getting NoClassDefFoundError in cmd (Windows). The problem is that readInts(args[0]) class is deprecated. 
My programming skills are not good enough to fix it by myself. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readInts` is a method not a class.

```
/**
 * Reads all ints from stdin.
 * @deprecated For more consistency, use {@link #readAllInts()}
 */
public static int[] readInts() {
    return readAllInts();
}
```

As you can see here, the fix is just to use `readAllInts()`. However, deprecated methods should still work. Verify that you have setup `stdlib.jar` correctly, and are including it in the class path when compiling.

Comment: thanks! This entry works in cmd - java  -cp .;stdlib.jar ThreeSum http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/14analysis/1Kints.txt

Comment: And how to make it work from Eclipse? I mean how to enter txt file?